# Grouping form controls using dictionary, collection or class

Tags: vb.net, winforms, class, dictionary, collections

I am trying to categorize/group my form controls in order to be able to apply changes to several of them in one go. For instance, I may want to enable/disable them.

Should I add the form controls to collections, dictionaries or should I create classes?

Ideally I would like to create categories and sub-categories. I would define properties for the categories and the sub-categories. The properties of the categories would be passed to the "child" sub-categories. 
For instance, if the font of CategoryA is "arial" the font of subcategories A1, A2 ect would also be "arial".
I would only "store" the objects in the sub-categories. If you have ideas how I could such architecture please make some suggestions.

At this stage I have created a dictionary. I am  quite sure that I cannot create the categories/sub-categories I would like to with dictionaries and collections but it's still a first step in the right direction (bulk changes).

The problem I am facing with dictionaries is that the properties/methods specific to the controls do not display in the IntelliSense. How can I make them available?

```
    Public dct As New Dictionary(Of Object, Integer)

    Dim ctlr As Control
    Dim i As Integer

        i = 1

        For Each ctlr In Controls
            dct.Add(ctlr.Name, i)
            i = i + 1
        Next

        For Each Item In dct
            'Enabled is not available
            Item.Enabled = False
        Next
```

Comment: Did you try using a `Dictionary(Of Control, Integer)`? Your current code will still work, it is just that there is no way to know that Object is definitely Control, and so Intellisense won't offer the Control properties.

Comment: There's also the Tab property where you can add your extra information

Comment: @A Friend: yes I have and it does not make any change

Comment: Do you have Option Explicit On in your project? You'll need to do `For each Item as Control In dct`

Comment: @ A Friend: No, it's not on. Adding "As Control" generates the error "Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of System.Windows.Forms.Control, Integer)' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'"

Comment: Neither Object nor Control will have the specific properties for Textbox or ComboBox because they are all different things.  This all seems like a wasted effort because the fact that some subset are all TextBox seems irrelevant to the logical function (such as Shipper info vs Ship To info for instance).  And of course using `ofType) you can always quickly get the TextBox or whatever subset when needed

Answer (score 0):

I would dump the dictionary and use a List(Of T). Add the actual object to the list and the properties should be available. In any case here is the dictionary code. Comments and explanation in-line.

```
Public dct As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
        'I changed Object to String because that is what you are
        'adding to the dictionary. I don't see where the .Value
        'is ever used so I suggest changint to List(Of Button) or List(Of Control)
Private Sub OpCode2()

            Dim ctlr As Control
            Dim i As Integer

            i = 1
            'This saves the name of the control to the key of the dictionary
            'This is just a string unrelated to a control as far as the dictionary knows
            For Each ctlr In Controls
                dct.Add(ctlr.Name, i)
                i = i + 1
            Next

            For Each Item As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In dct
                'The .Find method returns a control using the control name
                Dim ctrl As Control = Controls.Find(Item.Key, True).FirstOrDefault()
                'The properties inherited from Control will be available in intellisense
                'If you need a property of a particular type of control 
                'you will need to cast ctrl to the type you need
                ctrl.Enabled = False
            Next
End Sub
```

The following code uses List(Of T) and is much shorter and easier to read.

```
Public lst As New List(Of Control)
Private Sub OpCode2()
        Dim ctlr As Control
        For Each ctlr In Controls
            lst.Add(ctlr)
        Next

        For Each Item In lst
            'The list actually contains a reference to the control
            'so properties of Control are available
            Item.Enabled = False
        Next
End Sub
```